# Create Lumen 5.5 - React Project from scratch

Tags: reactjs, lumen

I need to create a new project using reactJS and lumen 5.5 and i was installed lumen 5.5 and reactJS. but then i was stuck, so i have some questions:
where is the position of the reactJS folders should be?
how i can add a react component in the home page with data-source from lumen api?
how we can integrate between them?
what the content of package.json should be?
i will appreciate any clear answer, because i was spent alot of time to make an integration between them without any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lumen isn't intended to have views, it's primarily intended to be a lightweight API framework. If you want views and a front end, you should use Laravel. Which also comes with a [react preset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/frontend#using-react) to get you started right away. Laravel also has [API routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#basic-routing) built in that you can use for your API. The good news is that your code from Lumen should be fairly easy to transfer over to a Laravel project.